# How to check alerts details in SAP GRC database?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-basis, netweaver

I am trying to find the issue details generated as part of the control execution process in GRC database tables. For e.g. I have control ABC with one business rule which runs on the base ECC system and generates an alert with 5 exceptions. I can see these exceptions when I open the rule exceptions in NWBC but unable to locate them in the GRC backend.

I tried searching the table `GRPC_EXCP_DETLS` and I see ABAP XML in the output field of description. Issue status is available at the header level but I want to check the details of the issue (e.g. which GL codes are deficient) in the backend. Is it possible?